# FileNotFoundException when running jar file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have the following code:

```
package test;


import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SWTTest test=new SWTTest(new Display());
        test.run();
    }


    private Shell shell;
    private Display display;


    public SWTTest(Display main_display) {
        display=main_display;

        shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
        shell.setText("Test window");
        shell.setBackgroundImage(new Image(display,"./image/blue_screen.jpg"));
    }

    public void run() {

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

This is compiling and running. the problem is when I export it as a jar file.
Just to make sure I did it correctly:
Right-click on the project->export...->Runnable Jar file->choosing the right launch configuration, and then 'Finish'.
It creates a jar file, but then when I run it from terminal, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: i/o error (java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./image/blue_screen.jpg (No such file or directory))
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.SWTTest.<init>(SWTTest.java:31)
    at test.SWTTest.main(SWTTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./image/blue_screen.jpg (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Compatibility.newFileInputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Why is it running on Eclipse, but not as a jar file?
Why is it all of a sudden can't find the image?

(I will also mention that I added new Source Folder to my project and named it "image", which now sits next to the "src" folder - what I'm trying to say is that "image" folder is a Source folder in my Eclipse project).
So what am I missing here?

Comment: Remove leading `./` from path.

Comment: Because you need to use the classloader to get your file. In Eclipse you are abusing the fact the the code is running exploded.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, what does it mean: "the code is running exploded"?
m0skit0, tried it, didn't work even in eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your images are stored in the jar, you need to load them as a resource. Along these lines, but you should close the stream.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("something.png"));
```

When you run in Eclipse, you have the images local in your directory, so you can see them with the usual File objects, but not when they are in the jar itself.

Comment: I tried it too, but getResource() returns URL object, which is not applicable for the Image constructor...

Comment: You might want to check out a similar post like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915725/locating-resources-within-a-jar-package  You'll likely find you're answer there.

Comment: Use a BufferedImage, BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("something.png"));

Comment: @so.very.tired Just as another hint, if you store your images in the src directory in Eclipse, they will automatically be copied over to your bin directory, this will allow you to have the images load with the same code whether you ran it from Eclipse or from a Jar, pretty helpful for development. If you have some other tricky setup you can search for how to set up your class path and try to organize around it.

Comment: That would also be best @so.very.tired